# Xcode Swift Attach tabs to search bar

Tags: ios, xcode

Does anyone know how I could possibly create the "top", "people", "tags", and "places" tab in xcode? I would like to know how to attach tabs to my search bar. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to filter your search? If so, I highly recommend you to take a look at [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) tutorial, the section called "Creating a Scope Bar to Filter Result" (one of the last).